# How do I assemble the mechanical parts of panel mount switch? (lock ring, lock washer, nut, etc)

Tags: switches, mechanical-assembly

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm not familiar with the different mechanical parts of a simple switch.

For example, I've purchased [this switch](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/633-M2011SS1W02) and it includes:

- Switch
- "Lockwasher" ("tooth" washer)
- "Locking ring"
- 2x nut

[image: NKK SPST Switch]

Is this the correct order (from inside box to outside), switch -> nut -> lockwasher -> [panel] -> locking ring -> nut?  If so, which direction does the locking ring face?

Comment: [Switch Mounting Procedures](https://www.nidec-copal-electronics.com/e/catalog/switch/panel-mounting-procedures_fujisoku-brand.pdf#page=2)  Locking ring goes up or down dependent if there is an opening to lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

The "official" way is:

1. one nut first
2. locating ring, bent tab towards the panel, to fit in a hole in the panel
3. panel
4. lockwasher
5. second nut.

Edit: for a "cleaner" front panel, you might put the lock washer on second, before the locating ring.  For thicker panels, various bits may be omitted to make it fit...

Another way:

1. one nut
2. locking ring, tab away from panel
3. lock washer
4. panel
5. second nut.

In both cases, the first nut is adjusted so the bushing sticks through the panel far enough to get the second nut on.

The second method depends on the lock washer to prevent rotation - but a toggle switch is not likely to rotate anyway.